# End to End testing in Cucumber or combining test cases to run as an end to end test

Tags: ruby, cucumber

We are using cucumber automate our web-based application and our mobile side application.  We have test cases that enable for us to validate we would have to set it in our website then check mobile application to see if it worked.  Here's the question
- Is it possible in cucumber to combine or reference an existing test cases from another suite to run AFTER say I set a setting in our web portal?
- Example
Test Case 
- Set feature A to On in web portal
- In order for Feature A to be checked it it worked I have to go to Mobile App and check

Is there such a thing as
Execute test case 1 then go to another suite and execute test case 2?
or should we just combine the whole end to end even though test case 2 already exists as an independent test?

Comment: Is this what you are asking about? https://relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps/nested-steps . Also maybe see [this comment](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/237#issuecomment-53555187) in which Matt Wynne seems to have regrets about ever implementing this concept.

Comment: Seems like the one I am describing but now I want to check out helper methods as per comment. Thanks @engineersmnky!!